# Using curl to update mysql when curl spits out json

Tags: php, json, curl, twitter, pycurl

Ok a rather strange question here (or maybe not)

I am trying to pull tweets out of twitter using curl here is the command

```
curl http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=XXhashtagXX -XXuserXX:XXpassXX
```

Every where there is an x that is a place for variables like twitter username and password and also the hashtag to look for.

And this is using the twitter restful api which alerts your script everytime a change was made.

In a console this curl command works perfectly but now i just need to take the output and save it to my mysql tables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where lies your difficulty? Can't your script read the output file, or don't you know how to insert stuff into the database?

Comment: See [PHP cURL](http://php.net/curl) to fetch the JSON response,  [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) to decode to an array/object, [curl_setopt](http://php.net/curl_setopt) for authentication (more specifically CURLOPT_USERPWD) and [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) for database insertion. Or, show some code if you want a specific answer.

Comment: ah yeah sorry i am fairly interested in how you would code a script that contains the curl code above. I know the php and i know the json_decode. But how do you wait for a stream then react when it calls back at you. Because at the moment i only know how to put curl in the command line and see the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IRL buddy. Here's what you want pretty much.

chmod a+x watch_twitter.sh
./watch_twitter.sh

or

sh watch_twitter.sh

**watch_twitter.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
nohup curl http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=hashtag -uusername:password\!\! -o test.txt -N &
nohup php watch_test.php &
exit
```

**watch_test.php**

```
<?php
while(1){
        echo ".";
        $data = file_get_contents('test.txt');
        if($data){
                file_put_contents('test.txt',"");
                $dataarry = explode("\n",$data);
                foreach($dataarry as $data){
                        print_r(json_decode(trim($data)));
                }
                echo "FOUND SOMETHING!";
        }
        sleep(1);
}
print_r($data);
?>
```